# Reference a key in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

In application.yml, how can I reference a key indicated here: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

application.yml

```
foo:
  bar: ${server.address}/verify
```

I expect that the value is **localhost/verify** but it is throwing unresolve placeholder.

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'server.address' in string value "${server.address}/verify"
```

Answer (score 4):

That page lists the properties you can set within the application.yml to override defaults. The `server.address` doesn't have a default value. As such there is no property defined to put into that placeholder.