# Jhipster registry gets wrong IP from Eureka (Docker deploy)

Tags: spring, jhipster, netflix-eureka

We are having the following problem, when deploying several microservices, randomly sometimes one of them is registered in the registry with an incorrect IP. I understand that eureka is incorrectly identifying the IP of the container ...
We tested several solutions like this application.yml config, but we did not get it working properly. Any ideas?

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        hostname: ${server.address}
        ip-address: ${server.address}
```

I saw this solution here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jhipster-dev/n7s7OTgT18E/RtZ3O4hlEwAJ

But this config throws "Could not resolve placeholder "server.address" in string value". This make sense when I read this: [Reference a key in application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361586/reference-a-key-in-application-yml)

Comment: are you ensuring all your services register them self with custom instance ids for eureka? maybe eureka gives services old ips, remembering by id

Comment: Yes, the instance id is a random value: instanceId: sd_api:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

Comment: I notice that the problem happens when I redirect a port in a container. If the container exposes a port, then Eureka registers a wrong IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@snowblind This is most probably a problem with docker container networking. Actually when doing initial registration, Eureka only uses what is available from inside the application. So it will determine it's address with something like java.net.InetAddress and then propagate this value to the Registry to advertize how the service can be reached. However in your case it seems to be reporting wrong informations.

So first make sure you always map the container port to the same host port. Alternatively you can use docker host networking (--net=host) so that your container share the same network interface as your host. This is possible in docker-compose by adding `net: "host"` to your service descption.

Another idea would be to use hostname based Eureka registration as opposed to the IP based one that we configure by default (prefer-ip-adress = true), but I cannot guarantee that it will work as I've never tried it myself, please refer to Eureka docs if you want to do this.

Comment: I use network_mode: host on my docker-compose and still happening same problem. With hostnames it works, but we need to use ip's (some other services need this info). Thanks for the help!